# Replace groupByKey with reduceByKey in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd, distributed-computing

Hello I often need to use `groupByKey` in my code but I know it's a very heavy operation. Since I'm working to improve performance I was wondering if my approach to remove all `groupByKey` calls is efficient.

I was used to create an RDD from another RDD and creating pair of type (Int, Int)

`rdd1 = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2 , 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)]`

and since I needed to obtain something like this:

`[(1, [2, 3]), (2 , [3, 4]), (3, [5])]`

what I used was `out = rdd1.groupByKey` but since this approach might be very problematic with huge datasets I thought to use this solution:

Instead of creating my RDD `rdd1` of pairs of type (Int, Int) what I do is creating it of pairs of type (Int, List[Int]) so my `rdd1` was something like this

`rdd1 = [(1, [2]), (1, [3]), (2 , [3]), (2, [4]), (3, [5])]`

but this time to reach the same result I used `reduceByKey(_ ::: _)` joining all the values by key, which is supposed to be faster. Do you think using this approach might improve performance? I'm afraid of this type (Int, List[Int]) isn't stupid creating a pair which value is a list containing only 1 element?

Do you think is there a faster way to reach the same result, using some other method? Thank you.

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing, but using `aggregateByKey` or `combineByKey` instead, with an empty List as intializer, and then list.add and list.addAll for the combiner and merger, respectively. This would avoid creating single-element lists in the first place. I believed that `groupByKey` would be already optimized to work better in such cases, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should use `reduceByKey` if your **end** result is to be

```
[(1, [2, 3]), (2 , [3, 4]), (3, [5])]
```

Why? Because this is what `groupByKey` is made for, so it probably does it best.

The problem with `groupByKey` is that you usually don't need a list (or an array) of all values with the same key, but something you can obtain from this list. If you don't really need the list, you probably can do the reduction in the same step as the shuffle, using `reduceByKey`.

The two advantages of `reduceByKey`:

- it can start reduction before shuffling (reduce values that are on the same executor, to avoid unnecessary network payload)
- it never loads the whole array of values with the same key into memory. This is important in huge datasets, where the array may be several GB large.

In your case, as you presented it, the first point is not very important (since there is no real reduction of the data, just concatenation), the second point does not apply since you want the whole list.

However, I strongly suggest that you think about if you really need the whole list, or if this is just a step in your computation, especially if you're working with large datasets.

Comment: I'm working in GraphX with graphs so those in the list are VertexId's, so yes I need the list. Yes, this answer made think.

Answer (score 3):

> Since I'm working to improve performance I was wondering if my approach to remove all groupByKey calls is efficient.

Check out `RDD.toDebugString` to see the logical plan of your RDD transformation. That should give you pretty good overview of how fast (or not) your action is going to be.

Avoid `ShuffledRDD` since they incur shuffle operation that is usually very expensive.

As to your idea of using `reduceByKey` consider `keyBy` it before, e.g.

```
rdd.keyBy(_.kind).reduceByKey(....)
```

You may also consider `aggregateByKey` as the most general transformation (that sits behind `groupBy` and relatives).

And the last but not least, `groupBy` has two variants that allow for defining number of partitions or `Partitioner`. These can avoid expensive shuffle.

Read up on [org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).

Use web UI to have a better insight on the performance of your "queries". Knowing your data will help a lot. Spend enough time on it too (as the time to optimize your query may be wasted otherwise).

Comment: `keyBy` created (K, V) tuple from non-pair RDD. OP's RDD is key-value RDD, so he doesn't have to use keyBy :) Secondly, groupByKey can be very inefficient, more than reducing values. In OP's question we can see that he reduces values, so reduceByKey should be used, not groupByKey

Answer (score 2):

May be a bit late to answer this. It might help others.

```
val tuples = List((1, 2), (1, 3), (2 , 3), (2, 4), (3, 5))
val context = getContext() // get Spark Context.
val tuplesRDD = context.parallelize(tuples)

val list = mutable.MutableList.empty[Int]
val addItemsToList = (s: mutable.MutableList[Int], v : Int) => s +=  v
val mergeLists = (x: mutable.MutableList[Int], 
                  y: mutable.MutableList[Int]) => x ++= y

val groupByKey = tuplesRDD.aggregateByKey(list)(addItemsToList, mergeLists)
groupByKey.cache()
groupByKey.foreach(x => println(x))
```

**Output**

(1,MutableList(2, 3))
(2,MutableList(3, 4))
(3,MutableList(5))