# Spark - What are the usecase for groupByKey over reduceByKey

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

There are strong reasons why groupByKey should be avoid and prefer reduceByKey to send optimize netwokr bandwidth.

https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Are there any cases where groupby is *really needed* and cant be solved with reduceByKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some use cases where groupBy is preferable.

- Where the "grouped" items should not be aggregated of any sort , and the items should be send as they are - [Replace groupByKey with reduceByKey in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518450/replace-groupbykey-with-reducebykey-in-spark)
- and in the operations which are NOT associative etc .. reduceByKey can not be used. Only option is groupByKey